# Flash: bend progress bar tweening

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I want to create a custom progress-bar.Progress bar is bend in curvature.
I have 2 bend images, One is tunnel and other is Bar image.
Currently in attached FLA file, progress-bar is at 100 percent stage.
How can i achieve Tweening so that Bar layer fills Tunnel Layer which is bend ?

FLA File:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/06dagw25v39wdg7/PBar.fla

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the bar layer on top of the tunnel layer and scale it so it covers the tunnel layer completely. Then you can use a rectangular mask that determines how much of the bar layer should be visible. Easiest way is to probably animate the mask where on frame 1 nothing of the bar layer is visible and on say frame 100 the whole bar layer is visible.